# mapping values from groupby to Dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply, pandas-groupby

I work on

https://www.kaggle.com/c/competitive-data-science-final-project

and I want to write my own scaler. To do this, I want to make a new column which will be the mean of revenue based on shop_id and year quarter. by this value I intend to scale revenue data. So This topic is about **getting values from groupby series into dataframe** .

groupby series:

```
all_sales.groupby(by=["year","quarter","shop_id"]).revenue.mean()
```

```
// ..........................................
// : year : quarter : shop_id :             :
// :......:.........:.........:.............:
// : 2013 :       1 :       0 :  673.366136 :
// :      :         :       1 :  570.307679 :
// :      :         :       2 : 1060.903808 :
// :      :         :       3 :  742.238854 :
// :      :         :       4 :  793.700453 :
// :      :         :       5 :  634.066920 :
// :......:.........:.........:.............:
```

I wanted to map it, I searched for other solutions But I found only solutions where a value is fixed - for example If I wanted to map a mean value for shop_id 54, i would simply use apply(...). i was thinking about using lambda, map, applymap

here is the dataset - starting phase:

```
+---------+------------+----------------+---------+---------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------+
|         |    date    | date_block_num | shop_id | item_id | item_price | item_cnt_day | latitude  | longitude | item_category_id | category_number | weekday | revenue | year | quarter | Q_avg |
+---------+------------+----------------+---------+---------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------+
| 2580899 | 2013-01-01 |              0 |      28 |   10832 |      399.0 |          1.0 | 55.604232 | 37.491973 |               40 |               4 |       1 |   399.0 | 2013 |       1 |     0 |
|  835894 | 2013-01-01 |              0 |      41 |   12750 |      119.0 |          1.0 | 47.289983 | 39.847001 |               40 |               4 |       1 |   119.0 | 2013 |       1 |     0 |
|  519245 | 2013-01-01 |              0 |      28 |    1249 |      299.0 |          1.0 | 55.604232 | 37.491973 |               55 |              12 |       1 |   299.0 | 2013 |       1 |     0 |
| 2578875 | 2013-01-01 |              0 |      42 |   10555 |      199.0 |          1.0 | 59.932022 | 30.359193 |               55 |              12 |       1 |   199.0 | 2013 |       1 |     0 |
|  303337 | 2013-01-01 |              0 |       7 |    3325 |     1199.0 |          1.0 | 51.696833 | 39.273076 |               30 |              14 |       1 |  1199.0 | 2013 |       1 |     0 |
| 2508902 | 2013-01-01 |              0 |      27 |   12623 |      649.0 |          1.0 | 55.658314 | 37.845215 |               37 |               4 |       1 |   649.0 | 2013 |       1 |     0 |
|  330640 | 2013-01-01 |              0 |      19 |   17707 |      899.0 |          1.0 | 51.737952 | 36.192223 |               19 |               8 |       1 |   899.0 | 2013 |       1 |     0 |
|  316521 | 2013-01-01 |              0 |       7 |    3693 |      299.5 |          1.0 | 51.696833 | 39.273076 |               21 |               8 |       1 |   299.5 | 2013 |       1 |     0 |
|  835868 | 2013-01-01 |              0 |      15 |   12750 |      119.0 |          1.0 | 54.516081 | 36.246664 |               40 |               4 |       1 |   119.0 | 2013 |       1 |     0 |
|   60981 | 2013-01-01 |              0 |      28 |    5272 |      598.5 |          1.0 | 55.604232 | 37.491973 |               30 |              14 |       1 |   598.5 | 2013 |       1 |     0 |
+---------+------------+----------------+---------+---------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------+
```

1. too slow but it should work;

```
avg=[]
for i in range(len(all_sales)):
    shopid=all_sales.shop_id.iloc[i]
    year=all_sales.year.iloc[i]
    quarter=all_sales.quarter.iloc[i]
    avg.append(all_sales.groupby(by=["year","quarter","shop_id"]).revenue.mean().loc[year].loc[quarter].loc[shopid])
    print(i)
all_sales.Q_avg=avg
```

2. faster but does not save values in Q_Avg:

```
all_sales["Q_avg"]=0
for year in [2013,2014,2015]:
    for quar in [1,2,3,4]:
        for shopid in all_sales[(all_sales.year==year)&(all_sales.quarter==quar)].shop_id.unique():
            all_sales[(all_sales.year==year)&(all_sales.quarter==quar)&(all_sales.shop_id==shopid)].Q_avg=all_sales.groupby(by=["year","quarter","shop_id"]).revenue.mean().loc[year].loc[quar].loc[shopid]
```

Target (in Q_avg):

```
// ...............................................................................................................................................................................................................
// :         :    date    : date_block_num : shop_id : item_id : item_price : item_cnt_day : latitude  : longitude : item_category_id : category_number : weekday : revenue : year : quarter :       Q_avg       :
// :.........:............:................:.........:.........:............:..............:...........:...........:..................:.................:.........:.........:......:.........:...................:
// : 2580899 : 2013-01-01 :              0 :      28 :   10832 :      399.0 :          1.0 : 55.604232 : 37.491973 :               40 :               4 :       1 :   399.0 : 2013 :       1 : 846.1797826935596 :
// :  835894 : 2013-01-01 :              0 :      41 :   12750 :      119.0 :          1.0 : 47.289983 : 39.847001 :               40 :               4 :       1 :   119.0 : 2013 :       1 : 992.6000783392107 :
// :  519245 : 2013-01-01 :              0 :      28 :    1249 :      299.0 :          1.0 : 55.604232 : 37.491973 :               55 :              12 :       1 :   299.0 : 2013 :       1 : 846.1797826935596 :
// : 2578875 : 2013-01-01 :              0 :      42 :   10555 :      199.0 :          1.0 : 59.932022 : 30.359193 :               55 :              12 :       1 :   199.0 : 2013 :       1 : 980.5774001136369 :
// :  303337 : 2013-01-01 :              0 :       7 :    3325 :     1199.0 :          1.0 : 51.696833 : 39.273076 :               30 :              14 :       1 :  1199.0 : 2013 :       1 : 868.1195129284332 :
// :.........:............:................:.........:.........:............:..............:...........:...........:..................:.................:.........:.........:......:.........:...................:
```

My code is too slow and I search for faster solution that work. So I expect the last column Q_avg to be filled with values from groupby (based on year, quarter, shop_id)

Comment: your question is not very clear, can you explain more. what you looking for?

Comment: edited. I try to add values from groupby series into the corresponding row in dataframe all_sales

Comment: do you trying to fill the mean value of revenue in new column based on the these three features "["year","quarter","shop_id"]" ? If this is the problem then first create these column and then just use groupby method to take out the revenue mean and directly assign it to new column like " df['new_column_name'] = df.groupby(your features ).revenue.mean()"

Comment: You should add another dataframe as `expected output`. Data analyst can more easily read data, than text.

Comment: @amannagariya yes, thats the case. I tried your advice, but it goes with an error as I expected: "TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index"

Comment: share your code or past the kaggle link

Comment: all_sales["Q_avg"]=all_sales.groupby(by=["year","quarter","shop_id"]).revenue.mean()

Comment: anyone help, please?